# Export inception output to spacy's training input format

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using INCEpTION 0.11.0  (https://inception-project.github.io/) to annotate my training data.
I would like to use python spacy to use this training data.  I could see couple of format in Inception to which I can exported to  but I am not sure which one is best suited for spacy.

[image]

I could not see any document about converting these exported file to space’s format.

I could write a new script to do this conversion. Before doing that I was wondering is someone already solved this and can give some advice? Which export  format  I should choose so that it will be easier to convert  to spacy’s format?

Comment: Which tasks are you training?

Comment: I am trying to create custom training data set and in my search I found out about inception and thought of trying it.

Answer (score 3):

Exporting your data as CONLLU is likely the most straightforward approach. SpaCy can convert CONLLU documents to its expected format using the the [converter script](https://spacy.io/api/cli#convert): `python -m spacy convert /path/to/input/doc.connlu /path/to/output/doc.jsonl -c conllu`.

You'll find that it supports the conversion of CONLL documents, but it isn't immediately obvious *which* CONLL format is supported. You can try this by playing with the `-c` argument above.

Comment: Inception produced .conll document but it throwed an exception while converting to spacy's format. Either I am doing something wrong while annotating or  inception output is not correct.

Comment: .File "home/.pyenv/versions/legal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/converters/conllu2json.py", line 65, in read_conllx
    id_, word, lemma, pos, tag, morph, head, dep, _1, iob = parts
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 10, got 1)

Comment: Which version of spaCy do you have?

Comment: spaCy version    2.1.8
Platform         Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
Python version   3.7.4
Models           en